# Bootstrap2 container max-width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to build a page with `.container` having `max-width:750px;` 
I also will need to have several rows of `.span4` generated just by adding to the same `.row`

If I add `max-width` to `.container` then the `.span`s stops functioning correctly. 
If I use `.row-fluid` I get the correct width of the columns but on the first line they line up correctly and the second line they don't.

```
<style>
.container { max-width:750px;}
</style> 

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#F00">1</div>
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#9F0">2</div>
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#FF0">3</div>
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#939">4</div><!-- make new row -->
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#3CF">5</div> 
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#F00">6</div> 

    </div>  
</div>



<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#F00">1</div>
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#9F0">2</div>
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#FF0">3</div>
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#939">4</div><!-- make new row -->
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#3CF">5</div>
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#F00">6</div> 

    </div>  
</div>
```

I understand the 12 column CSS grid logic of bootstrap. The problem is not that my spans don't add up to 12.

[LIVE PREVIEW HERE](http://33tpm.com/bs2/)

Anyone?

Comment: This problem is happened to me once. I don't know how to fixed it, I just added class (or style) that set margin-left:0; to each first span of rows.

Comment: @ch.smrutiranjanparida, FYI, look likes you forget to include bootstrap 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because every span except the first one in row takes `margin-left`. To solve this either remove `margin-left` from the fourth span using custom CSS or you can have separate row class for every row. I suggest having separate row for each row is better, still it's your decision.

I suggest this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#F00">1</div>
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#9F0">2</div>
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#FF0">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#939">4</div><!-- make new row -->
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#3CF">5</div> 
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#F00">6</div> 
    </div>  
</div>
```